# Getting an exception from sending an email from gmail

Tags: c#

I am trying to email people using gmail. I am not certain why this is not working correctly. Below is the screenshot of the error thrown.

[image: Exception when emailing]

Below here is the code for setting up my mail client.

```
string body = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Data\MailTemplates\welcome.html");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sean.shydow", "password");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        message.From = new MailAddress("sean.shydow@gmail.com");
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            { return true; };
        message.To.Add("sean@gmail.com");
        message.Subject = subject.Text;
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        message.Body = body;
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

Comment: to see the console pic of the exception please right click and open in new window or tab.

Comment: It would help if at least the first few lines of your call stack were included as text.

Comment: @Sean, couldn't you post the text of the exception instead? A screenshot of a console app isn't very useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 587 is for TLS. As you're using SSL, try port 465 (see http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287 for more).

Also confirm that your machine can actually connect to the Gmail SMTP ports. Some ISPs block them to avoid botted machines becoming spam factories. Try `telnet smtp.google.com PORT` for `PORT`s 25, 465, and 587,. If you get a timeout, then you're likely firewalled from connecting to these ports outside a certain IP range.

Comment: Can your machine actually connect to the Gmail SMTP ports? Some ISPs block them to avoid botted machines being spam factories. Try `telnet smtp.google.com PORT` for `PORT`s 25, 465, and 587 (now edited into my answer).

Comment: hold on where am i putting telnet smtp.google.com and what am i doing with port 25 465 and 587? Sorry I am a little confused

Comment: `telnet` is a command line program that just opens a socket to an address and port, and lets you type down it, whilst echoing anything send from the remote end to your screen. In this case, it's a debugging aid. Google for `telnet on MYPLATFORM` for your platform for more.

Comment: Yea my machine is blocking ISPs so thanks so much for that information!
CHEERS!